# strong product $K_m$ $K_n$ equal to $K_ m,_n$

Tags: graph-theory

verify that strong product $K_m$  $K_n$ equal to $K_ m,_n$ . ($K_ m,_n$ is complement bipartite graph)
definition of strong product $G$ and $H$:

strong product of G and H is the graph denoted as $GH$, and defined by
$$V (G H) = {(g, h) | g ∈ V (G) and  ~h ∈ V (H)}$$,
E(G H) = edges of cartesian product union edges of direct product $G$ and $H$.

can you prove it?

Comment: Do you mean complete bipartite graph instead of complement bipartite graph for $K_{m,n}$?

Comment: Actually it cannot be the complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$ because $K_{m,n}$ has $m+n$ vertices but the strong product of $K_m$ and $K_n$ has $mn$ vertices. If you really refer to "complement bipartite graph" and not "complete bipartite graph" then what is it a complement of?

Comment: $K_m_n$ is complete graph with $mn$ vertices

Comment: Okay, you should edit the question to change it then.

Answer (score 1):

Let the strong product of $K_m$ and $K_n$ be $G$. Consider any pair of vertices $(g,h)$ and $(g_2,h_2)$ in $G$.

(1) If $h=h_2$ and $g\neq g_2$ then by definition of $K_m$, $g$ and $g_2$ are adjacent so $(g,h)$ and $(g_2,h_2)$ are adjacent.

(2) If $h\neq h_2$ and $g = g_2$ then by definition of $K_n$, $h$ and $h_2$ are adjacent so $(g,h)$ and $(g_2,h_2)$ are adjacent.

(3) If $h\neq h_2$ and $g \neq g_2$ then by definition of $K_m$, $g$ and $g_2$ are adjacent and by definition of $K_n$, $h$ and $h_2$ are adjacent so $(g,h)$ and $(g_2,h_2)$ are adjacent.

Hence any pair of vertices in $G$ are adjecent, also since $G$ has $mn$ vertices hence $G=K_{mn}$.